Typescript and AxiosError: Axios has two nested responses instead of one when there is an AxiosError
My api is working absolutely fine everywhere except when I try to do an if block for a potential Axios error. This is because the status is in response.response.status instead of response.status so Typescript throw the error Property 'response' does not exist on type 'AxiosResponse<any, any>'.
Can anyone help me with this?
Working with no AxiosError present:
postBoundary: async (boundary: CreateBoundary) => {
    const response = await axios.post(
      `${config.baseApiPath}boundary`,
      boundary
    );
    return response.data; //returns correctly
  }

Not working with Axios Error present:
postBoundary: async (boundary: CreateBoundary) => {
        const response = await axios.post(
          `${config.baseApiPath}boundary`,
          boundary
        );
        // when response has an Axios error response.status 
        // doesn't exist because there are two nested responses
        if (response.response.status === 
            HttpStatusCode.PayloadTooLarge) {
             throw new Error("Error");
         }
        return response.data;
        }


This is because when an Axios request fails, the error object has a different structure than a successful response.
import { AxiosError, HttpStatusCode } from 'axios';

postBoundary: async (boundary: CreateBoundary) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      `${config.baseApiPath}boundary`,
      boundary
    );
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    // First check if it's an AxiosError
    if (error instanceof AxiosError) {
      // Now we can safely access error.response
      if (error.response?.status === HttpStatusCode.PayloadTooLarge) {
        throw new Error("Payload too large");
      }
    }
    // Re-throw any other errors
    throw error;
  }
}


This looks like it would work but when response is an AxiosError it still hits return response.data for some reason

It seems the way to get it working is
postBoundary: async (boundary: CreateBoundary) => {   try {     const response = await axios.post(       ${config.baseApiPath}boundary`,
boundary
);
if (response instanceof AxiosError) {
  if (response.response?.status === HttpStatusCode.PayloadTooLarge) {
    throw new Error("Payload too large");
  }
}
return response.data

}`
